# JRebel Activation IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, activation, jrebel

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am working with IntelliJ and JRebel plugin version 6.5.1 .
To activate my license I am connecting to the "License Server".
The problem is this new plug in version does not have the "Use IDE proxy settings" check box and when I try to activate it returns an HTTP 407 error.
How can I configure the proxy ?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File/Settings, Appearance&Behaviour/System Settings/HTTP Proxy, Manual Proxy Configuration (assuming IDEA 14)